# SSH via python (paramiko) error: "'_EllipticCurvePublicKey' object has no attribute 'verify'"

Tags: python, ubuntu, ssh, paramiko

I am trying to connect to a SSH server using the python library paramiko.
The same code worked on the same computer before, but it started to show a warning when trying to connect. I can connect to the SSH server using the same computer and same users via terminal. The python code also works on other computers connected to the same LAN network.
I also tried to restart both pcs and reinstall paramiko with no success.

Following is the code and the warning message presented.

```
class SSH:
    def __init__(self, ip):
        self.ssh = SSHClient()
        self.ssh.load_system_host_keys()
        self.ssh.set_missing_host_key_policy(paramiko.AutoAddPolicy())
        self.ssh.connect(hostname=ip ,username='urs',password='pass')
```

Warning message:

```
Unknown exception: '_EllipticCurvePublicKey' object has no attribute 'verify'
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/paramiko/transport.py", line 1886, in run
    self.kex_engine.parse_next(ptype, m)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/paramiko/kex_ecdh_nist.py", line 47, in parse_next
    return self._parse_kexecdh_reply(m)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/paramiko/kex_ecdh_nist.py", line 105, in _parse_kexecdh_reply
    self.transport._verify_key(K_S, sig)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/paramiko/transport.py", line 1748, in _verify_key
    if not key.verify_ssh_sig(self.H, Message(sig)):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/paramiko/ecdsakey.py", line 216, in verify_ssh_sig
    self.verifying_key.verify(
AttributeError: '_EllipticCurvePublicKey' object has no attribute 'verify'
```

Do anybody have a suggestion about where the problem might be?
I tried to google and looked for the error here,but couldn't find it anywhere.
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I had the exact same error as now. I encountered this error with paramiko version 2.3.0. I downgraded to 2.1.2 and the operation i was doing proceeded normally.